# How is the VS2019 worklowf with cmake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I am using VS2019 and got a bit confused about the configuration of the project, on one side there is the CMakeLists.txt, on the other hand there is a VS configuration file. Also, i saw that it is not neccesary to create a build dir. So I wish to understand the CMake workflow within VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one tutorial that explains some about the workflow
[CMake and Visual Studio 2019](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=api&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7116&link=%5B%5B%229F1E006D78894848838A0970E2FF0BE9zoom%22,%22Object1%22,7116%5D,%5B%2271C91DEE3C5A4FDC8EC1114C7C18033Bzoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7116%5D%5D&rows=25)
VS 2019 tries to do as little as possible and uses the CMakeLists.txt files as project files. But there are some extra files to configure debug settings etc. How to start programs and there are also some functionality to collect data from tests executed